# Check if values are within a certain range of a separate dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I have the following two dataframes:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("AED","AED","CFR","DRR","DRR","DRR","UN","PO"),
             dates = as.POSIXct(c("2018-05-17 09:52:00","2018-05-17 10:49:00","2018-05-17 10:38:00","2018-05-17 11:29:00","2018-05-17 12:12:00","2018-05-17 13:20:00","2018-05-17 14:28:00","2018-05-17 15:59:00")))

events <- data.frame(id = c("AED","CFR","DRR","DRR","UN"),
                 start = as.POSIXct(c("2018-05-17 10:00:00","2018-05-17 10:18:00","2018-05-17 11:18:00","2018-05-17 13:10:00","2018-05-17 14:18:00")),
                 end = as.POSIXct(c("2018-05-17 11:56:00","2018-05-17 12:23:00","2018-05-17 12:01:00","2018-05-17 14:18:00",NA)))
```

By unique id, I want to compare each date in df against the respective date ranges listed in the events dataframe (each row of the events dataframe is considered its own time range), so that I get the following result:

```
result <- data.frame(id = c("AED","AED","CFR","DRR","DRR","DRR","UN","PO"),
                 dates = c("2018-05-17 09:52:00","2018-05-17 10:49:00","2018-05-17 10:38:00","2018-05-17 11:29:00","2018-05-17 12:12:00","2018-05-17 13:20:00","2018-05-17 14:28:00","2018-05-17 15:59:00"),
                 inRange = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
                 outsideRange = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))
```

If an id from df is not in events then return FALSE for both inRange and outsideRange; if a df date is greater then the event$start, but events$end is NA, then inRange should be TRUE

I'm hoping to apply the solution to a much larger dataset of at least 500,000 rows.

Comment: you got so many abandoned/open question. You can accept answers on those question so those will be helpful for future users.

Answer (score 1):

in base R:

```
df2 <- merge(df,events)
df2 <- within(df2, inRange <- dates > start & dates < end)
df2 <- aggregate(inRange ~ dates,df2,any)
#                 dates inRange
# 1 2018-05-17 09:52:00   FALSE
# 2 2018-05-17 09:56:00   FALSE
# 3 2018-05-17 10:38:00    TRUE
# 4 2018-05-17 11:29:00    TRUE
# 5 2018-05-17 12:12:00   FALSE
# 6 2018-05-17 13:20:00   FALSE
# 7 2018-05-17 14:28:00    TRUE
# 8 2018-05-17 15:59:00   FALSE
```

The first merge is a cartesian product here, if your data is big we might be better off extracting the day first on both sides then merging.

That means doing this before the above code:

```
df$year <- as.Date(df$dates)
events$year <- as.Date(events$start) # assuming start and end are always on same day
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `non-equi` update join using `data.table`. Join `df` and `events` on `dates>=start` and `dates<=end`. Set the `inRange` column as `TRUE` for matching records.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
setDT(events)

df[events, on=c("dates>=start", "dates<=end"), inRange := TRUE]
df
#                  dates inRange
# 1: 2018-05-17 09:52:00      NA
# 2: 2018-05-17 09:56:00      NA
# 3: 2018-05-17 10:38:00    TRUE
# 4: 2018-05-17 11:29:00    TRUE
# 5: 2018-05-17 12:12:00      NA
# 6: 2018-05-17 13:20:00      NA
# 7: 2018-05-17 14:28:00    TRUE
# 8: 2018-05-17 15:59:00      NA
#
```

Answer (score 1):

If `events` do not overlap, then sort the start and end coordinates and use `findInterval()` to determined those dates that are in the odd-numbered intervals

```
x = with(events, sort(c(start, end)))
df$inRange = findInterval(df$dates, x) %% 2 == 1
```

If `events` do overlap, then create a vector of all events, figure out how to place them in order, and do so

```
times <- with(events, c(start, end))
o <- order(times)
times <- times[o]
```

create an `event` vector that is `1` when a start occurs, `-1` when an end occurs, and place these events in order

```
event <- rep(c(1, -1), each = nrow(events))[o]
```

calculate the 'coverage', the number of events that are currently in effect.

```
cvg <- cumsum(event)
```

Finally, create an updated `events` data frame where starts and ends are derived from the 'start' values where coverage is 1 and the event is a 'start' event, and likewise for ends

```
times[ (event == 1 & cvg == 1) | (event == -1 & cvg == 0) ]
```

and proceed as above.

Putting this together we have

```
reduce_int <- function(start, end) {
    x <- c(start, end)
    o <- order(x)
    x <- x[o]

    event <- rep(c(1, -1), each = nrow(events))[o]
    cvg <- cumsum(event)

    x[ (event == 1 & cvg == 1) | (event == -1 & cvg == 0) ]
}

overlaps <- function(x, events) {
    vec <- reduce_int(event$start, event$end)
    findInterval(x, vec) %% 2 == 1
}
```

with use

```
df$inRange <- overlaps(df$dates, events)
```